# Protractor Auto Content Issues in Eclipse and Visual Studio Code

Tags: eclipse, protractor

I am new to protractor and I have set up protractor projects in both visual studio and eclipse.

From screenshots you can check that protractor global variable , browser does not show ***waitforAngualrEnabled*** property in eclipse
[image]

While in visual studio code , it does display
[image]

Why eclipse is not suggesting this property ?
Please help. Thanks...

Comment: confirm whether you are importing the `browser` from protractor when you are using protractor.

Comment: when using browser from eclipse , i used it directly as protractor global variable. But in visual studio code i used it as :                                                          
 var pro = require("protractor");                                                                                                pro.browser........blah blah commands

Comment: Only the `browser` from protractor gives you the `waitForAngularEnabled`

Comment: what is browser from protractor ??

Comment: you have to import your browser from protractor like you did in Vs Code.

Comment: i have not imported browser in VS code. I imported protractor . I used the same .js file in eclipse. Can you please share the exact code for importing browser.

Comment: add `import { browser} from 'protractor';` in your spec(in VS code).